# Minute by minute breakdown of log data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (Excel sheet, whatever...) containing PeopleSoft login information with three columns: Login Time, Logout Time, Time Spent.

My manager has been asked to use that to provide a minute by minute run down of concurrent logins for the entire data set (day).

So, the SELECT for the table is like so:

```
SELECT LOGIN.Login, LOGIN.[Log out], LOGIN.[Time in]
FROM LOGIN;
```

Output looks like this:

```
Login               Log out             Time in
11/1/10 12:36 AM    11/1/10 12:42 AM    0:06
...
```

What I need is:

```
Time                    Concurrent_Logins  
11/1/10 12:36 AM        16
```

...

So, this is quite complicated. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

What you'll want to do is build a table that contains every minute for the day. There are a number of ways you can do this, just search for "tally table", etc.

Once you have a table containing all of your minutes (in datetime format), it should be straightforward.

Join your login table to the minutes table on minute between login/logout and do a count(*) for each minute.

Answer (score 1):

Derek's solution is the way to go.

http://www.ridgway.co.za/archive/2007/11/23/using-a-common-table-expression-cte-to-generate-a-date.aspx explain a way to generate on the fly the timetable

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY
GO
DECLARE @STARTDATE DATETIME
DECLARE @ENDDATE DATETIME

SELECT @STARTDATE = '02/01/2011 01:00', @ENDDATE = '03/01/2011 01:00'
;

WITH DateRange(MyDateTime) AS
(
    SELECT
      @STARTDATE AS MyDateTime
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        DATEADD(minute, 1, MyDateTime) AS MyDateTime
    FROM
        DateRange
    WHERE
        MyDateTime < @ENDDATE
)
SELECT MyDateTime, ConcurrentConnections = COUNT(*) 
       FROM DateRange INNER JOIN [LOGIN] ON MyDateTime >= [LogIn] AND MyDateTime <= [Log Out]
   OPTION (MaxRecursion 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem I would first get the min and the max datetime values from the dataset. This would provide the time range from which we will need to determine the count of concurrent logins. After getting the time range, I would do a loop to populate a table with each minute in the range and the count of concurrent logins for that minute. After populating the table I would select from it where concurrent login count > 0, this would be my result set. I use SQL Server, you may need to convert some of the syntax to another DBMS.

```
-- To get the min and max of the time range
DECLARE @min datetime, @max datetime
SELECT @min = MIN(l.[Login]), @max = MAX(l.[Log out])
  FROM [LOGIN] l

-- now make a table to how the minutes and the counts
CREATE TABLE #Result
(
    [Time] datetime,
    [count] int
)

-- now do a loop to fill each minute between @min and @max
DECLARE @currentTime datetime, @count int
SELECT @currentTime = @min, @count = 0
-- go from @min to @max
WHILE @currentTime < @max
BEGIN
    -- get the count of concurrent logins for @currentTime
    SELECT @count = COUNT(*)
      FROM [LOGIN] l
     WHERE @currentTime between l.[Login] and l.[Log out]

    -- insert into our results table
    INSERT #Result ([Time], [count]) VALUES (@currentTime, @count)

    -- increment @currentTime for next pass
    SELECT @currentTime = DATEADD(minute, 1, @currentTime) 
END

-- select final result (where count > 0)
SELECT *
  FROM #Result
 WHERE [count] > 0

-- clean up our temp table
DROP TABLE #Result
```